# XBAP with FireFox and Windows 7

Tags: firefox, windows-7, xbap

Firefox depends on an extension and plugin installed by the .NET 3.5 installer to run XBAPs.  Unfortunately, in Windows 7 the .NET 3.5 runtime is already installed.

Does anyone know how to get a hold of these plugins/extensions so you can actually deploy XBAPs to FireFox on Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn out, the answer is to copy the DLL of the extension out of another (presumably XP) machine that **can** run the .NET 3.5 runtime and deploy it.

I'm uncertain of the legality of this maneuver, but it works.

Comment: What is the name of this DLL?

Comment: Found it: NPWPF.dll. I took the DLL from a WinXP installation with .NET 3.5 SP1 under C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Windows Presentation Foundation\NPWPF.dll, placed it into C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\plugins, restarted firefox and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for that, You'd think MS would release an installer or register the plugin with mozilla... dont know how im going to roll this fix out to clients :(

Comment: It is super lame that it takes a hack like this to get xbabs to work in FireFox.

Comment: Just for the record, this fix also works for Google Chrome :)