# debug an xbap on firefox?

Tags: wpf, firefox

I am starting to write an xbap (wpf web app).

I create a new project and run it and Firefox fails (it just keeps trying to open it with "Windows Presentation Foundation Host).

I know that Firefox and Microsoft don't really see eye to eye, but surely there is a way to do this now days?

[Saw this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500940/xbap-with-firefox-and-windows-7) that shows a hack of copying out a DLL from a Windows XP machine.  But my users will not do that (I don't even want to do that!)

Does this mean I have to abandon Firefox as my default browser until I am done developing my xbap?

**NOTE:** I am using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and Firefox 3.6.12

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly your problem is, but here is a [Scott Hanselman blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FirefoxWPFAndXBAP.aspx) detailing a WPF application deployed as an XBAP (not XBAB) using VS 2008 with .NET 3.5. It doesn't say anything about WPF 4 (and the .NET 4 runtime, the post is from 2008) or what version of Firefox he was playing with but I hope this demonstrates it is possible and gives you a starting point for more detailed investigations.

**Edit -** Well, I should have dug a little deeper. It appears that Windows 7 won't support XBAPs in FireFox. There is a Firefox Add-on to Support XBAPs and Loose XAML that is installed with the .NET 3.5 runtime but it is not included in Windows 7 and [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716877.aspx) suggests it can't be installed on Windows 7.

You could run [IE Tab Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10909/) (Firefox plug-in) and get it to default to IE when you open something from the localhost.

Comment: I will take a look at the page.  Thanks for the correcting me on the xbap vs xbab.  I was saying "xbap" in my head but it just typed out wrong!

Comment: I am starting to see that this is a windows 7 only issue.  (That is why one fix is to copy a dll from xp to win 7).  Since Scott's post was from 2008, I bet he was not using windows 7 :)